# get, have etc a grasp of something vs a grip on something

Tags: expressions, differences, idioms, expression-choice, nuance

Is there a difference between having/getting etc a grasp of something and a grip on something, when you mean knowledge/understanding?

---

Merriam Webster defines grip , in this sense, as ["mental grasp"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grip), which makes pinpointing any difference, if there is one, even harder.

---

A few examples:

- can't seem to get a grip on calculus (Webster)
- a remarkable grasp of the subject (Webster)
- Her grasp of the issues was impressive; Steve has a good grasp of the European legal system; We're still trying to get a grasp on the situation. (Longman)
- I’m just trying to get a grip on what’s happening; She was losing her grip on reality. (Longman)

Answer (score 2):

The words **grip** and **grasp** are such near synonyms that the difference between expressions *to get a grip* and *to get a grasp* may be a matter of one's preference or idiolect.  Consider primary definitions offered up by Google:

> Grip... take and keep a firm hold of; grasp tightly.
>
> Grasp... a firm hold or grip.

**Grip** is rooted in OE - *grippa* (v) or *gripe* (n); **Grasp** is linked to ME, possibly *grope*.

**Grip** *may* have a slightly more informal or idiosyncratic sense when applied to a subject (such as calculus), and **Grasp** may be idiomatically inappropriate in the sense of self-control (**Get a grasp on yourself** doesn't necessarily sound right), but as a matter of hard and fast definitions, the denotative difference between the words will be subtle at best.

As part of common expressions, **grip** may be firmer and perhaps more forceful: after all, Beowulf grapples Grendel in a *"mund-gripe"*, tearing his talon off in the process. While not taken lightly, the possibly younger **grasp** *may* be just a bit more deliberate, and therefore more appropriate to an idea than an object or enemy.  Even so, Shakespeare placed "a barren Scepter in my Gripe" (*Macbeth*, III i) only to see a legion of editors turn **Gripe** into **grasp**.

So this one may be tough to call.

Comment: Not sure why we've both been downvoted - your answer's as good as mine :o)

Comment: @WillCrawford - hard to tell - obviously someone doesn't like certain uncertainty. I like your answer as well, and am upvoting...

Comment: reciprocating :o)

Answer (score 2):

Although the words themselves are near perfect synonyms, the uses you're struggling with are long-established (and subtle).

***Get a grip*** means to take control of yourself, and possibly exercise authority (natural or official) in a situation. The origin of ***grip***(s) in this context is a battlefield metaphor, stemming from [grappling](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/to+grapple+with) *(which uses **come to grips with** in its definition)*. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-to-grips) puts it a little more directly:

> (often foll by with)
>    a. to deal with (a problem or subject)
>    b. **to tackle (an assailant)**

and like many other sources gives the alternate form ***come*** to grips with.

***Get a grasp*** means - the subtlety - to *understand* something.

It ***might*** help to think of ***grip*** as getting hold of something to ***wield*** it *(or **wrestle** with it)*, versus to ***carry*** or simply ***keep hold of*** it. It's not a black-and-white distinction, but one is a bit more active than the other¹.

It doesn't help that we use *grasp* more like the first sense in phrases like *graps the nettle*, but sometimes the distinction is useful; for example you could replace both uses with *master* (a subject or situation) ... and lose that difference in meaning.

The use of *grasp* in reference to a field of study, is again more about "getting it into your head" and *couldn't get a grasp* has a sense like *couldn't get a foothold* in climbing (and I've heard the latter used in a figurative sense about academic study too).

¹ More anecdata: https://www.quora.com/Is-the-expression-to-come-to-grips-with-something-similar-to-to-come-to-terms-with-something/answer/Robert-Harvey-41